# Do I have to prepare hotel booking, travel agenda or flight ticket when I apply for Korea tourist visa from Japan?

Tags: japan, south-korea

I'm a foreigner working in Japan so I have residence card here (my card will last till 2024)
I'm planning to go to Korea next January. From the website I see that I just need to fill out the visa application form, prepare my passport, residence card, photo as well as work certificate.
Even it is not written in the website, but do I need to prepare hotel booking, travel agenda, flight ticket or prove my finance ability when I apply for Korea tourist visa from Japan?